# Bicycle rear tyres getting stuck

Tags: tire, wheels

I just got a east man 26 inch bicycle recently,  and just the very day i got it the rear tyre starts getting stucked while riding.

[image]

Comment: It looks like the rear axle is not tightly fastened and is sliding, allowing the tire to slip to one side.

Comment: It should be obvious, but is the frame wide enough to properly accommodate the wide tire?

Answer (score 5):

Note that rubbing can be seen on the other side from where the tire is currently rubbing, which leads me to believe its more than a loose axle.

First thing to check is is the wheel seated in the dropouts correctly and the axle tight. If this is good, check the axle bearings. Hold the rim/tire - does the wheel wiggle from side to side?  Spin the wheel and check it is true, make sure the tire and wheel do not wobble from side to side and rub the frame as the tire turns.

Check the space between the frame and tire. Its possible a tire wider than the frame can accommodate has been installed.

Last problem could be wheel dish - is the rim in the center of the frame, or off to one side?

Answer (score 4):

Yes - I get the same when I don't secure the rear axle on my bike tight enough, and the chain pulls the right-hand side forward, which makes the tyre hit the left chainstay.

The fix is to back-off the QR or nuts that hold the rear wheel in place.  Leave the bike standing normally, don't put it upside-down.

Make sure the wheel is sitting at the top of the dropout slots.

If its got axle nuts then tighten the left-side nut.

Then use one hand to clamp down the rear brake lever (or a strap).
Use one foot to press on the wheel (about the middle of your photograph) to get the spacing even on both sides between tyre and chainstay.
 While doing all that, tighten the QR or the other wheel nut.
You may benefit from an assistant.

At the end, you should be able to free-spin the rear wheel without it touching the chainstays at any point.

If your rear rim has side-to-side wobble then it is "out of true" and needs other work as well.